# How do do a join on has_many_attached Active Storage association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I would like to do a DB query that finds all records that have files attached.

```rb
class Departure 
  has_many_attached :pre_trip_documents
end
```

However this fails:

```rb
Departure.joins(:pre_trip_documents).to_sql => #ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Departure' to association named 'pre_trip_documents'; perhaps you misspelled it?)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
Departure.joins(:pre_trip_documents_attachments)
```

This will make more sense if you look at the source of `has_many_attached`, which you can find [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Macros.html#method-i-has_many_attached).

To summarize, `has_many_attached :pre_trip_documents` results in:

```
has_many :"pre_trip_documents_attachments", -> { where(name: "pre_trip_documents") }, as: :record, class_name: "ActiveStorage::Attachment" ...
```

So calling `Departure.joins(:pre_trip_documents_attachments)` gives you:

```
SELECT "departures".* FROM "departures" INNER JOIN 
"active_storage_attachments" ON 
"active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = "departures"."id" AND 
"active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = 'Departure' AND 
"active_storage_attachments"."name" = 'pre_trip_documents'
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Probably you have to check the `blobs` instead of the `pre_trip_documents` association

Adding

```rb
has_many :pre_trip_documents_attachments, class_name: 'ActiveStorage::Attachment'
has_many :pre_trip_documents_blobs, through: :pre_trip_documents_attachments, class_name: 'ActiveStorage::Blob', source: :blob
```

You will be able to do

```rb
Departure.joins(:pre_trip_documents_blobs)
```

To see those attachments

More about: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

### UPDATE

Looking on the `blobs` was the solution for the problem that I faced. But as @weilandia answer said, it will be better to check first the `attachments`

```rb
Departure.joins(:pre_trip_documents_attachments)
```

Comment: is there a reason you have to join `blobs` instead of `attachments` ?

Comment: In my case was the final solution, I tried with attachments but didn't work, however if isn't your case will be better to check the attachments